# declare init script load after it dependences , or declare run levels for it

Tags: init.d

I create an init script for wildfly 10, but after reboot it loads before it dependences applications. 
How can I change that it will load as last process ?

I know that I can change run levels on update-rc.d, but what is correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies also run as init.d scripts you can change the ordering by modifying the number before the script name in the symlinks in /etc/rcX.d/

E.g. in one of my servers /etc/rc5.d/ contains:

```
K01apache-htcacheclean  S01dns-clean         S01lxcfs          S01rsyslog
```

To ensure your script starts last, prefix it with a number higher than its dependencies (or S99 to ensure it is the very last script to run)

Comment: I tried something else , I add values of [start] [kill]. For example I add                    update-rc.d ssh defaults 10 90   # start first and killed last                                              update-rc.d rsyslog defaults 20 80

Comment: I will try you suggestion  too